# Pourquoi écrit-on "avec de la musique" dans ce cas ?

Tags: grammaire, sens

Bonjour,

Dans une lettre à Gaston Gallimard, Céline écrit : "Au point de vue émotif ce récit est assez voisin de ce qu'on obtient ou devrait obtenir **avec de la** musique".

Pourquoi il écrit "avec **de** la musique" et non ***avec la musique***, sans la préposition "de" ?

[Lettre autographe signée à Gaston Gallimard](http://classes.bnf.fr/livre/grand/1352.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'article partitif permet de ne pas considérer la musique comme un tout générique, homogène et indivisible mais comme quelque chose dont on extrait des morceaux.

Dans sa lettre, Céline ne compare pas **la** littérature avec **la** musique mais une œuvre (son manuscrit, une création littéraire) avec d'autres œuvres (de la musique, des créations musicales).

La tournure *avec **de la** musique* permet aussi de tuer dans l'œuf tout risque d'ambiguïté alors que l'article défini *avec **la** musique* aurait pu être soupçonné de faire référence à une musique particulière évoquée auparavant.

Answer (score 0):

À mon avis il n'y a pas, dans ce cas particulier, de véritable différence. Les deux phrases suivantes sont équivalentes.

- Elle se relaxe avec de la musique.
- Elle se relaxe avec la musique.

La différence est celle qu'il y a entre les deux phrases suivantes.

- Elle écoute de la musique pour se relaxer.
- Elle écoute la musique pour se relaxer.

On ne trouve pas dans les livres Google d'exemples contenant « relaxe avec (de) la », mais il y en a pour « écouter de (la) musique », et ils montrent que la même chose est exprimée dans les deux cas.

([ref. **la**](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Rem%C3%A9diation_orthophonique_par_la_musiqu/MoiqDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A9couter+la+musique+pour%22&pg=PA172&printsec=frontcover)) Ils proposent d'écouter la musique pour se détendre, se concentrer, lâcher prise, s'imprégner de rythmes divers, d'atmosphères variées.

([réf. **la**](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_b%C3%A9gaiements_comprendre_et_agir/syntDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A9couter+la+musique+pour%22&pg=PA93&printsec=frontcover)) prendre sa place, regarder l'autre, les autres, jouer sa propre partition. Elles proposent d'écouter la musique pour se détendre, se concentrer .

([réf. **de la**](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Choisissez_votre_destin_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9tique/XdVTDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A9couter+de+la+musique+pour%22&pg=PT124&printsec=frontcover))  Lorsque j'aborde avec mes patients la nécessité d'écouter de la musique pour stabiliser leur maladie, je ressens comme un doute chez eux.

([réf. **de la**](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/S%C3%A9r%C3%A9nade_pour_un_cerveau_musicien/T-BUDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A9couter+de+la+musique+pour%22&pg=PT101&printsec=frontcover)) Elle continue d'ailleurs d'aimer et d'écouter de la musique pour les émotions ressenties.

([réf. **de la**](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/En_harmonie_avec_Dieu/VyknDQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22%C3%A9couter+de+la+musique+pour%22&pg=PA31&printsec=frontcover)) Il comprit alors que le fait d'écouter de la musique pour trouver un remède à ses problèmes était en fait une illusion, une solution transitoire qui ne lui ..

Dans d'autres cas il peut y avoir une différence.

- On pourrait se demander si le seul moyen d'écouter la musique pour pouvoir la comprendre consiste à se concentrer sur le fil du discours dans une ... (*comprendre toute la musique à partir de l'écoute d'une certaine partie de toute la création musicale*)
- On pourrait se demander si le seul moyen d'écouter de la musique pour pouvoir la comprendre consiste à se concentrer sur le fil du discours dans une ... (*comprendre cette partie que l'on écoute seulement*)